# Django 2.0.1 with CKEditor doesn't work on admin page

Tags: python, django, static, ckeditor

**I tried to install CKeditor but couldn't figure out a way.**

Steps I tried

- pip install django-ckeditor
- Add 'ckeditor' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.
- Run the collectstatic
- CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor" to my settings

and

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = RichTextField()
```

***when I requested the admin page for proper model, I can only get blank white page.
There is no error on terminal. CKeditor files returns 302 HTTP.***

Screenshot from my admin page

[image: Screenshot from my admin page]

***it is strange I can see related ckeditor things on DOM.
am I missing something?***

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you got this figured out or not. I spent the best part of 3 hours making it work for me.

I saw there was a 404:

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[27/May/2018 13:50:02] "GET /admin/projects/blogproject/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9674
[27/May/2018 13:50:02] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
[27/May/2018 13:50:04] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditorconfig.js?t=H8DA HTTP/1.1" 404 1709
[27/May/2018 13:50:05] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditorskins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=H8DA HTTP/1.1" 404 1763
[27/May/2018 13:50:05] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditorlang/en.js?t=H8DA HTTP/1.1" 404 1712
[27/May/2018 13:52:35] "GET /admin/projects/blogproject/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9674
[27/May/2018 13:52:35] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
[27/May/2018 13:52:37] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditorconfig.js?t=H8DA HTTP/1.1" 404 1709
[27/May/2018 13:52:38] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditorskins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=H8DA HTTP/1.1" 404 1763
[27/May/2018 13:52:38] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditorlang/en.js?t=H8DA HTTP/1.1" 404 1712
```

So Changed ths line from:

```
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor"
```

to: (just added a slash to the end)

```
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
```

The Widget is now avaliable in Admin for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the location of static files. Actually, server can't find the static files needed to render ckeditor's widgets.

**The simple solution**:

You need to upload the contents of the static folder inside the ckeditor package into the static folder of your project (albeit manually!).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, turns out I was using `STATIC_ROOT` in my `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` and thus redirecting to:

`staticfiles/ckeditor/ckeditor` (i.e. the static folder on the server or hard drive, where you collect with collectstatic)

which is not relevant for the browser. I solved it by using `STATIC_URL` and thus giving the address:

`/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/` (i.e. the url)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow these steps:

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'app1',
    'app2',
    'crispy_forms',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'ckeditor',
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    "default": {
        "removePlugins": "stylesheetparser",
        "allowedContent":True,
        "width": "100%",
    }
}

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR = 'utils.get_filename'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

And then you should run the following code in your terminal:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

My django-admin ss:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI08E.png)

If you have made the model and template settings in your project, you should not get an error.